# JSON Cyclic object value exception when trying to update user's data in localStorage

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I'm currently learning web development with The Odin Project curriculum. My project is a to do list that optionally can have a login system that users can store data. Even though this is not required for project submission I've spent a great deal of time getting what I've got so far and I know there can be a work around for this so I don't want to give up trying to find a solution.

We're not using frameworks or libraries for the moment except for webpack to improve our workflow. Also, we haven't touched any back-end concepts just yet, instead we're encouraged to use localStorage and JSON functions such as parse and stringify to store user's app session.

My worst nightmare now is the cyclic value exception that comes out every time I try to save user's data on logout. Honestly, I try to understand the cyclic value concept but still don't get it. That said, my efforts to make the login system work have been directed to create new objects, static values and other sorts of workarounds to come to the conclusion that the problem is in the JSON.stringify function.

These are the classes involved in the issue. Can anyone help out sorting out this please?

login-panel.js

```js
import Session from "./session";
export default class LoginPanel{

  static logOut (username, password, id, data, innerHTML){
    localStorage.removeItem(id);
    let logOutSession = new Session(username, password);
    logOutSession.id = id;
    logOutSession.data = data;
    logOutSession.innerHTML = innerHTML;
    localStorage.setItem(id+'-data', JSON.stringify(logOutSession.data));
    localStorage.setItem(id+'-HTML', JSON.stringify(logOutSession.innerHTML));
    document.getElementById(id).parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById(id));
  }

  render(){
    let innerHTML = ["<h2>Call it a day</h2>",
                    "<h4>Login</h4>",
                    "<p id = 'login-prompt'></p>",
                    "<div class ='username'>",
                    "<label for='user'>Username</label>",
                    "<input type='text' name='user' id = 'usr'>",
                    "</div>",
                    "<div class ='password'>",
                    "<label for='password'>Password</label>",
                    "<input type='password' name='password' id = 'pass'>",
                    "</div>",
                    "<button id='login'>Login</button>",
                    "<button id='sign-up'>Sign up</button>"].join('');
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 'panel';
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    document.getElementById('panel').innerHTML = innerHTML;

    document.getElementById('login').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
     if(localStorage.getItem(document.getElementById('usr').value+'-session')){
        let session = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(document.getElementById('usr').value+'-session')); 
        if(document.getElementById('pass').value==session.password){
          //render session content to html here!
          alert('You can call it a day');
        }else{
          alert('Wrong password');
        }
      }else{
        alert('User does not exit, do you want to sign up?');
      }
    }); 

    document.getElementById('sign-up').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      if(localStorage.getItem(document.getElementById('usr').value+'-session')){
        alert('Please login');
        return;
      }else{
        let session = new Session(document.getElementById('usr').value,document.getElementById('pass').value);
        localStorage.setItem(session.id+'-data', JSON.stringify(session.data));
        localStorage.setItem(session.id+'-HTML', JSON.stringify(session.innerHTML));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

session.js

```
import Project from "./project";

export default class Session {
  data = [];
  div = document.createElement('div');
  innerHTML = ["<button id='add-P'>Add Project</button>",
              "<button id='log-out'>Log Out</button>"].join('');

  constructor(username, password){
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.id = username+'-session';

    this.div.id = this.id; 
    this.div.className = 'session';
    this.div.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    document.body.appendChild(this.div);
    
    document.getElementById(this.div.children[0].id).addEventListener('click', ()=>{this.addProject();});
    document.getElementById('log-out').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
      LoginPanel.logOut(this.username, this.password, this.id, this.data, this.innerHTML)
    });

  }

  addProject(){
    this.data.push(new Project(this));
    ++Project.ID;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Session.data` contains circular references. `Session.data` is an array of `Project` objects. But every `Project` has a reference to the `Session` that contains it.

Objects with circular references can't be converted to JSON, because it would go into an infinite recursion converting each level. JSON has no way of indicating that an object should refer back to a previous instance.

You need to redesign what you save to local storage, so it just holds the details that you need to save in order to recreate the to-do list, rather than saving the entire class instances.

Note also that JSON just stores simple objects and arrays, the class information is discarded.

Comment: Hi Barmar! Thanks a lot! At this point I'm restructuring the project since the way it is right now is not flowing as I want. Your answer is definitely a supportive argument for making this decision, when things don't go smoothly something mustn't be right with them. Cheers!